# Boost.ASIO how to use strands with c++20 coroutines

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, boost-asio

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

namespace io = boost::asio;

class test {
public:
    test(io::any_io_executor e) : exe{ std::move(e) } {}

    io::awaitable<void> delay(size_t sec) {
        io::steady_timer t{ exe };
        t.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds{ sec });
        co_await t.async_wait(io::use_awaitable);
    }

    io::awaitable<void> print_and_delay(int num) {
        std::cout << num << '\n';
        co_await delay(1);
    }

    io::awaitable<void> d_print() {
        co_await print_and_delay(1);
        co_await print_and_delay(2);
        co_await print_and_delay(3);
    }

    void start() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i != 3; ++i) {
            io::co_spawn(exe, d_print(), io::detached);
        }
    }

protected:
    io::any_io_executor exe;
};

int main() {
    io::io_context ctx;
    test t{ ctx.get_executor() };
    t.start();
    ctx.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
(delay 1 second)
2
2
2
(delay 1 second)
3
3
3
(delay 1 second)
```

Now I want to make the execution of `d_print` serial: only one `d_print` coroutine runs at once.

Expected output:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

With each line delayed for 1 second.

Can I achieve this through the usage of `strand`s?

What I want to do is adding something like `synchorized(st) {` around the three `print_and_delay`s. When the executor tries to run the following coroutines,block them until the running coroutine finishes executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strands **already** protect the code posted through it against concurrent execution.

The behaviour is **correct**, and adding the putative "synchronized" keyword would not change it either.

What you are after is **not** protection against concurrent/overlapping execution - because it is already working. Instead you want to avoid posting the new coroutine (`d_print`) instance before the previous stopped.

### Solution

The classical solution to this is queuing.

> Similar requirements come up with e.g. full-duplex IO where outgoing messages have to be queued to avoid interleaving writes.

Strands are still useful to avoid unsynchronized access to the queue:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/344f2ec0c3e3a09a)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

class test {
  public:
    test(asio::any_io_executor e) : strand_{make_strand(std::move(e))} {}

    static asio::awaitable<void> delay(size_t sec) {
        co_await asio::steady_timer{co_await asio::this_coro::executor, std::chrono::seconds{sec}} //
            .async_wait(asio::use_awaitable);
    }

    asio::awaitable<void> print_and_delay(int num) {
        std::cout << num << '\n';
        co_await delay(1);
    }

    asio::awaitable<void> d_print() {
        co_await print_and_delay(1);
        co_await print_and_delay(2);
        co_await print_and_delay(3);
    }

    void start() {
        post(strand_, std::bind(&test::do_start, this));
    }

  private:
    asio::strand<asio::any_io_executor> strand_;

    std::deque<asio::awaitable<void> > queue_;

    asio::awaitable<void> drain_queue() { // runs on strand
        while (!queue_.empty()) {
            co_await std::move(queue_.front());
            queue_.pop_front();
        }
    }

    void do_start() { // runs on strand
        bool not_running = queue_.empty();

        for (size_t i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
            queue_.push_back(d_print());

        if (not_running)
            co_spawn(strand_, std::bind(&test::drain_queue, this), asio::detached);
    }
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context ctx;

    test t{ctx.get_executor()};
    t.start();

    ctx.run();
}
```

[image]

### Other Thoughts

You can also use the experimental Asio Channels feature, which could simplify thread-safety and give more flexibility.